# Finding eigenvectors and sketching phase portrait

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

\begin{align}
x'(t)&=x(1-10y)\\
y'(t)&=y(1-10x)
\end{align}

One of the equilibrium points of this system is $(0,0)$. I was trying to draw a phase portrait with this point. Now I figured this is an $\textit{unstable node}$ as the linearized  system has two repeated positive real eigenvalues. Now I need an eigenvector corresponding to it to get a parallel trajectory through $(0,0)$ to initiate the sketch of the phase portrait. But I've got stuck here while trying to get the eigenvector.

\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{pmatrix}&=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any vector satisfies $I\cdot v = 1\cdot v$, that means the whole space is the eigenspace, any basis is an eigenvector basis.